# Sending message to SQS queue posing issues

Tags: java, amazon-sqs

I am looping over a list of strings in Java and sending message to an SQS queue like this.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<TimberLogSummary>> entry : logMap
                            .entrySet()) {
                    String fleetName = entry.getKey();

                    for (final TimberLogSummary summary : entry.getValue()) {
                            String job = summary.getLogId() + "#" + summary.getLogName()
                                            + "#" + fleetName;
                            this.sendJobToJobQueue(job);
                    }

            }
```

I have given permissions to everybody in my SQS queue , when I see this executing not all messages are pushed to the queue and after sometime messages start to get deleted automatically leaving the size of queue to zero.

Does anybody have any clue what is wrong here ?

Comment: Please format the code properly when posting so others can look at it easily.

Comment: None of the code shown sends anything to SQS.  It sounds like you are saying the messages are getting deleted from SQS.  Are you running something which is reading from the queue and deleting messages?  What is the MessageRetentionPeriod?